# What is the right way to handle a picture upload now that background tasks are not allowed?

Tags: android, cordova, background-task

For starters, let me just be clear that I have no experience with developing 
 for Android, and this is my first project with it.

I'm using Cordova to make what should be a simple app for use within my company, and as a requirement several pictures must be taken and uploaded to our server.

It initially worked, while the test device had been using Android 7, but after updating to Android 8.1, uploading of pictures  no longer work, or only the first picture is uploaded.

Checking adb logcat, I found messages like "ActivityManager: Background start not allowed" and "BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed".

Searching the web, it seems that targetting an older SDK should have worked, but so far I had no luck with it.

I have also tried plugins that should have started a foreground service as a workaround, but it didn't work either.

Since looking for workarounds isn't working and they may stop working later, I would like to know if there's a new, correct way to handle uploads that I just havent found yet.

This is not for customers outside the company, so even if I have to keep the user in a loading screen showing upload progress, it won't be a problem, rather it may even be useful, so they know for sure the upload was successful

To clarify something: the upload already used to work, and still works with Android 7, I don't a need a library for that. 
  My problem is that Android 8 won't allow the upload to be done as a background service, and I haven't figured out how to avoid using a background service with Cordova.

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with Cordova. 
I recommend using OKHTTP to do the picture uploads. In this example I am showing how my apps send pictures to a PHP script on the server side.
Set things up in your activity:

```
private File tmpDir;
tmpDir = new File(getFilesDir(),"Your Android File Directory");
if (!tmpDir.exists()) tmpDir.mkdirs();

String fpath = "Directory_path_of_your_picture";
String fname = "Filename_of_your_picture";
File fbody = new File(tmpDir, fname);

// Upload the file by making a call to the Uploader class
Uploader(fbody, fname, fpath);
```

The Uploader class looks like this:

```
    // Upload Class
    public static int Uploader(File file, String fname, String fpath) throws Exception {
        int statusCode = -1;
        final URL url = new URL("Your_Upload_Script");

        OkHttpClient.Builder b = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        b.readTimeout(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        b.writeTimeout(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        b.connectTimeout(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        final OkHttpClient client = b.build();

        RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("filename", fname)
            .addFormDataPart("MAX_FILE_SIZE","300000")
            .addFormDataPart("filepath", fpath)
            .addFormDataPart("uploadedfile", fname,
                    RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_TEXT, file))
            .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(requestBody)
            .build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            // Successful Upload
            statusCode = response.code();
        }
        return statusCode;
    }
```

Finally, set up the receiver script on the server like this (PHP version, but you may have different backend depending on your setup):

```
// PHP script on the server
<?php
    $fname = $_POST['filename'];
    $fpath = $_POST['filepath'];
    $target_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/" . $fpath . "/" . $fname;
    $upload_path = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'];
    if(move_uploaded_file($upload_path, $target_path)) {
        echo "Moved";
    } else {
        echo "Not Moved";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Java won't help, and I don't need a library to upload the files, since that used to work. The problem is that the upload is being created as a background service, and Android 8 won't allow it.

Comment: How large are the pics you are uploading? Dont think there is anything broken in Android services (fg or bg) specificaly with respect to performing uploads.

Comment: About 200k.  I don't think the problem is with uploads. Android 8 doesn't allow background services to be freely created anymore, and I can't find a way to avoid them (using Cordova/Phonegap)